# Javascript sort objects by created_date (desc) in array of arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

This is an overly simplified example, but I'm curious how I can return the objects in order by date (newest to oldest) without changed the array order at all:

```
let arrayOfArrays = [
    array1 = [
        object1 = {id: 1, name: 'object1', created_date: '2012-01-15'},
        object2 = {id: 2, name: 'object2', created_date: '2018-01-15'},
        object3 = {id: 3, name: 'object3', created_date: '2018-01-17'}
    ],
    array2 = [
        object4 = {... created_date: '2013-01-15'},
        object5 = {... created_date: '2017-01-15'},
        ...and so on...
    ],
    ...more arrays...
]
```

Here's an actual image of what I'm attempting to sort: 
[image]

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far?

Comment: This is not a valid array structure.

Comment: Type “javascript sort array by custom criteria” or similar into a search engine, and you should find more than enough results to get you started.

Comment: @eddie it is?!?!

Comment: To clarify: you want to sort the objects in the inner arrays?

Comment: @JonasW. Ohh i tried it and works fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the outer array, take every inner array and sort that:

```
 for(const array of arrayOfArrays) {
   array.sort(/*...*/);
 }
```

You can find out more on how *sort* works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript)

Comment: Actually, realizing that I'm really trying to sort just an array of objects and the reason it isn't working is that some of the objects are empty. It's an array of addresses and some of the addresses have an array of account objects.